# Windows Phone emulator does not work

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

My computer (32-bit) doesn't support Windows Phone emulator,which requires the 64-bit edition of windows 8.1 Pro (My computer windows 8.1 enterprise) and a computer that supports Hyper-V
what should i do to fixed it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run emulator, follow these steps:

1. Check if your processor supports SLAT. Here is a guide to check for this feature using CoreInfo: [How to Check if Your CPU Supports Second Level Address Translation](http://www.howtogeek.com/73318/how-to-check-if-your-cpu-supports-second-level-address-translation-slat/)
   If your processor doesn't, get a new processor/PC.
2. Install Windows 8.1 64 bit (both Pro and Enterprise will work).

Or you can simply deploy your app in a physical device (get a cheap Lumia 4XX or 5XX) and test.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you do will make the emulator run on 32bit Windows. Your only option is to install 64bit Windows.